# Use SqlDataReader and string array

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to use data reader to read a record and send the result to an array string.

I use a stored procedure to select data from 2 tables.

```
string ReqID = "";
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlc;
string[] textbox;
string ReqType;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ReqID"] != null)
        ReqID = this.Request.QueryString["ReqID"];

    sqlc = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "LoadReq";

    string[] textbox = new string[4];
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ReqID != "")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReqID", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = ReqID;
            cmd.Connection = sqlc;
            sqlc.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textbox[2] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FReqID"));
                textbox[3] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderDate"));
                textbox[4] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderTime"));
                textbox[5] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReqIP"));
                textbox[6] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Status"));
                textbox[7] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FileCode"));
                textbox[8] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"));
                textbox[9] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DOI"));
                textbox[10] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PubMedID"));
                textbox[11] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PaperCode"));


                LoadCorrectForm(textbox[8], textbox);
            }
        }
```

And my stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].LoadReq
@ReqID int = 0
AS
SELECT 
        Request.FReqID, Request.ReqIP, Request.OrderDate, Request.OrderTime,
        Request.[Status], Request.FileCode, Request.[Description],
        Details.[Type], Details.DOI, Details.PubMedID, Details.PaperCode, 
        Details.ISBN, Details.Title, Details.Journal, Details.BookTitle,
        Details.Conference, Details.[Year], Details.Publisher, Details.Edition, 
        Details.Vol, Details.Issue, Details.pp, Details.[Author(s)],
        Details.URL
     FROM 
        Request 
     INNER JOIN 
        Details ON Details.ID = Request.FreqID
     WHERE 
        (Request.ID = @ReqID)
```

But I get an error.

How should I edit my code to do this job?

Comment: you defined your array `textbox` with size of `4` and you are trying to set its element `11` ??

Comment: Why don't use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @user30551479 Or a datatable ? This may be helpful for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188717.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Habib, your array is too small. Consider this modification. Instead of this:

```
string[] textbox = new string[4];
```

or even this:

```
string[] textbox = new string[11];
```

Get rid of that line and do this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string[] textbox = new string[reader.FieldCount];
```

## Suggestions

In addition to the fix, there are some suggestions you should consider.

```
if (Request.QueryString["ReqID"] != null)
    ReqID = this.Request.QueryString["ReqID"];

using (SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoadReq", sqlc))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ReqID != "")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReqID", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = ReqID;

                sqlc.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string[] textbox = new string[reader.FieldCount];

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        textbox[2] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FReqID"));
                        textbox[3] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderDate"));
                        textbox[4] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderTime"));
                        textbox[5] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReqIP"));
                        textbox[6] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Status"));
                        textbox[7] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FileCode"));
                        textbox[8] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"));
                        textbox[9] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DOI"));
                        textbox[10] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PubMedID"));
                        textbox[11] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PaperCode"));

                        LoadCorrectForm(textbox[8], textbox);
                    }
                }
            }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the modified code there are a number of things to take note of:

1. I'm leveraging the `using` statement.
2. I'm leveraging a different `.ctor` of the `SqlCommand` to make it more concise.
3. I'm leveraging the `FieldCount` to determine the size of the array.
4. I'm **not sharing a connection instance.**
5. There are probably better data structures to use here.
6. Your current code flow *presumably* builds the connection and command even if they don't need to be used.

Point #1 is exceptionally important. The `using` statement ensures that the object created and used get disposed properly. Whenever you consume something that implements `IDisposable`, leverage the `using` statement.

Point #4 is almost as important as #1. *Do not share connection instances.* When you need one, build it, open it, use it, and dispose it.

Let me elaborate on #5 here. Instead of using a `string[]`, how about a `List<string>`. The `List<string>` is mutable (i.e. it can change size automatically). The code would be much easier because you could do something like this:

```
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FReqID")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderDate")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderTime")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ReqIP")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Status")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FileCode")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DOI")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PubMedID")));
textbox.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PaperCode")));
```

Then, if you needed to get it to a `string[]` you could just do this:

```
textbox.ToArray();
```

But, that may not work well for you here because you have an odd offset. You don't start inserting into the array until index `2`. So again, I can't really *say with certainty* there are better data structures.

Point #6 is just an interesting one to me. If it's a `PostBack` *or* the `ReqID` is an empty string you don't actually do anything. That leads me to believe that you should actually moving the creation of the connection and command objects inside those `if` statements, but that's just a logical flow I'd prefer over the current one.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: @user3051479, ehem, I'm pretty sure telling me what line that's on is pretty important to me being able to help you.

Comment: Line 42:                     textbox[2] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FReqID"));

Comment: @user3051479, is the value for that field `null` on that row?