# Retrieve value from database and assign it in to string array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, string

I would like to retrieve top ten data which has highst score value and assign them string array, here is my code but i actualy dont know very well how to do it.

```
string[] K = new string[10];
using (con3)
{
    con3.Open();               
    SqlCommand cms = con3.CreateCommand();
    cms.CommandText = "SELECT word FROM wordtable where word.score>= 1 LIMIT 10";
    cms.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
con3.Close();
```

Comment: Is `SELECT word` return single cell value??

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ExecuteNonQuery` if you want to execute a query, use `ExecuteReader`:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
using(var rd = cms.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(rd.Read())
    {
        string word = rd.GetString(0);
        words.Add(word);
    }
}
string[] K = words.ToArray();  // or fill your array without the list which is more error-prone.
```

Side-note: since you are using the `using`-statement the connection will be disposed at the end which will close it implicitly. So `con3.Close()` after the `using` is redundant.

Comment: @dpointttt: i haven't used a sql query because you have already used it. The sql query seems not to be a problem. `cms` is your `SqlCommand` with the `CommandText="SELECT word FROM wordtable where word.score>= 1 LIMIT 10"`. So i don't know why i should use `word.score` in my code. You are only selecting the `word`-column and not the `score`-column. Do you want both?

Answer (score 0):

Use **ExecuteReader** to read sql query return values.

For detailed information look following links:
[Fill an array (or arraylist) from SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370543/fill-an-array-or-arraylist-from-sqldatareader)
and 
[Use SqlDataReader and string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571047/use-sqldatareader-and-string-array)